# Using Runpod to wait for a container to be ready on port 80

Tags: python

Hello i'm trying to use runpod with python 3.11 to wait for a pod to be available before i start running commands to it.

I've installed runpod for python found here https://pypi.org/project/runpod/ but i can't figure out how to make it wait for the container to be ready i run

`pod_json = runpod.resume_pod(pod_id, 2)`

but this just starts the pod and does not consider there is a wait time before it can be used.

even after it started it says "http service port 80 not ready" for quite a few seconds before the pod can be interacted with.

I want to know how I can make my python script wait for the pod to become ready before i start sending commands to the pod